How to make a redirect after Login into Account
I use JWT token, send a request to receive a token, receive a token, how can I make a redirection in a convenient form after successfully completing the authentication procedure? I tried to do this via js (the solution works on the login page, we get a token and a link to go to, make a request to fetch and embed the response in the page, I understand that this is garbage), I would like to know if there is a mechanism in ASP .NET Core MVC, which itself will embed a token in all requests if it is required, rather than having to write various js scripts everywhere for this. I also want to know if it is possible to somehow redirect to another link and at the same time obtain the token through one method, in my case the Login method.
Login.cshtml
@model LoginViewModel

<h2>Login</h2>
<form id="loginForm" method="post" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login" asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div>
        <label asp-for="UserName"></label><br />
        <input asp-for="UserName" />
        <span asp-validation-for="UserName"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label asp-for="Password"></label><br />
        <input asp-for="Password" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Password"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label asp-for="RememberMe"></label><br />
        <input asp-for="RememberMe" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    </div>
</form>

<div id="content"></div>

@section Scripts {
    <script>
        document.getElementById('loginForm').addEventListener('submit', async function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            const form = event.target;
            const formData = new FormData(form);
            const username = formData.get('UserName');
            const password = formData.get('Password');

            const response = await fetch('/Account/Login', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    UserName: username,
                    Password: password
                })
            });
            if (response.ok) {
                const data = await response.json();
                localStorage.setItem('token', data.token.access_token);

                const returnUrl = form.getAttribute('asp-route-returnUrl');
                var newUrl = returnUrl ? returnUrl : '/Users/Index';
                loadPage(newUrl);
            } else {
                const errorText = await response.text();
                alert('Login failed: ' + errorText);
            }
        });
        async function loadPage(url) {
            const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
            const response = await fetch(url, {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
                }
            });

            if (response.ok) {
                const content = await response.text();
                document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = content;
            } else {
                alert('Failed to load the page: ' + response.statusText);
            }
        }
    </script>
}

AccountController.cs provides Registration, Login, Logout
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using MySteamDBMetacritic.Db;
using MySteamDBMetacritic.Models;
using MySteamDBMetacritic.ViewModels;
using System;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Runtime.Intrinsics.Arm;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;

namespace MySteamDBMetacritic.Controllers
{
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<AccountController> _logger;
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<User> _signInManager;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public AccountController(ILogger<AccountController> logger, ApplicationDbContext context, UserManager<User> userManager, SignInManager<User> signInManager, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _context = context;
            _logger = logger;
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _configuration = configuration;
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Register()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register([FromBody]RegisterViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                User user = new User { Email = model.Email, UserName = model.UserName };
                if (_userManager.Users.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Email==user.Email) != default(User))
                {
                    return View(model);
                }
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    result = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "User");
                    if (result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        _context.SaveChanges();
                        await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, false);
                        return Json(new { token = Token(model.UserName, model.Password), returnUrl = Url.Action("Index", "Game") });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                        {
                            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
                    }
                }
            }
            return View(model);
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            return View(new LoginViewModel { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody]LoginViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, false);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ReturnUrl) && Url.IsLocalUrl(model.ReturnUrl))
                    {
                        return Json(new { token = ((JsonResult)Token(model.UserName, model.Password)).Value, returnUrl = model.ReturnUrl});
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return Json(new { token = ((JsonResult)Token(model.UserName, model.Password)).Value, returnUrl = Url.Action("Index", "Game") });
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Incorrect username or password");
                }
            }
            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
        {

            await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Game");
        }
        public async Task<IActionResult> ChangePassword(int id)
        {
            User user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id.ToString());
            if (user == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            ChangePasswordViewModel model = new ChangePasswordViewModel { Id = user.Id, Email = user.Email };
            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ChangePassword(ChangePasswordViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                User user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(model.Id.ToString());
                if (user != null)
                {
                    var _passwordValidator = HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IPasswordValidator<User>)) as IPasswordValidator<User>;
                    var _passwordHasher = HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IPasswordHasher<User>)) as IPasswordHasher<User>;

                    IdentityResult result = await _passwordValidator.ValidateAsync(_userManager, user, model.NewPassword);
                    if (result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        user.PasswordHash = _passwordHasher.HashPassword(user, model.NewPassword);
                        await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
                        return RedirectToAction("Index");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                        {
                            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "User is missing");
                }
            }
            return View(model);
        }
        public IActionResult Token(string username, string password)
        {
            var identity = GetIdentity(username, password).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            if (identity == null)
            {
                return BadRequest(new { errorText = "Invalid username or password." });
            }

            var now = DateTime.Now;

            var jwt = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityToken(
                    issuer: _configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                    audience: _configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
            //notBefore: now,
            claims: identity.Claims,
                    //expires: now.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(double.Parse(_configuration["Jwt:ExpiresMinutes"]))),
                    signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["Jwt:Key"])), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256));
            var encodedJwt = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(jwt);

            var response = new
            {
                access_token = encodedJwt,
                username = identity.Name
            };

            return Json(response);
        }

        private async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GetIdentity(string username, string password)
        {
            User user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(username);
            if (user != null)
            {
                var claims = new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType, user.UserName)
                };
                claims.AddRange(_userManager.GetRolesAsync(user).Result.Select(x => new Claim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType, x)));
                ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Token", ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType, ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType);
                return claimsIdentity;
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}


UsersController.cs I decided to divide the functionality of the controller into two, in AccountController the user registers himself and can log in, in UserController the user with the admin role can change the password, create/delete users.
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using MySteamDBMetacritic.Models;
using MySteamDBMetacritic.ViewModels;
using System.Security.Claims;

namespace MySteamDBMetacritic.Controllers
{
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public class UsersController : Controller
    {
        UserManager<User> _userManager;

        public UsersController(UserManager<User> userManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var cl = HttpContext.User.Claims;
            return View(_userManager.Users.ToList()); 
        }

        public IActionResult Create() => View();

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(CreateUserViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                User user = new User { Email = model.Email, UserName = model.UserName };
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
                    }
                }
            }
            return View(model);
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id)
        {
            User user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id.ToString());
            if (user == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            EditUserViewModel model = new EditUserViewModel { Id = user.Id, Email = user.Email, UserName = user.UserName };
            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(EditUserViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                User user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(model.Id.ToString());
                if (user != null)
                {
                    user.Email = model.Email;
                    user.UserName = model.UserName;

                    var result = await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
                    if (result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Index");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                        {
                            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(int id)
        {
            User user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id.ToString());
            if (user != null)
            {
                IdentityResult result = await _userManager.DeleteAsync(user);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
}

I’m also open to any advice on the application as a whole, maybe there are mistakes that should be avoided in the future. Link on my project.

To make a redirect after logging into an account and embedding the JWT token in subsequent requests in ASP.NET Core MVC, configure JWT authentication in Startup.cs, use the SignInManager in the AccountController to issue tokens, and store the token in localStorage using JavaScript for future requests.

I already get a token and save it via js and I use 'SignInManger' or I didn't understood something?

Why are you mixing asp.net core Identity and Jwt together? Are there any specific reason? Now where do you want to redirect to after successful login?

I wanted to use only jwt, but I also added code from some articles in which identity was used for some reason, I’m just new to asp, I thought that maybe it’s also used in jwt somehow. If you tell me how to use only jwt, and at the same time save all functionality, I will be grateful

The way you are using is correct, not sure what exactly you want to know or what challenges you are facing. But in general if you want to use jwt to execute everything using token, then you have to pass the token in everything server request in order to access the endpoint securely.


That is, I can remove SignInManager, UserManager and write models for storing information and make a migration, then I will have to write the logic for adding/changing/deleting users myself and check whether it is there or not when logging in, or am I missing something?
And about adding a token to all requests, is there a way to do this as correctly and simply as possible, or will I really have to embed js into each View, which will have to somehow intercept the request and embed the token in the authorization header?



I would like to know if there is a mechanism in ASP .NET Core MVC,
which itself will embed a token in all requests if it is required,
rather than having to write various js scripts everywhere for this.

Well, in order to set Authorization request header while sending reuqest to API globally its quite easy if you use ajax request which has beforeSend attribute, where can set your token once then no where you don't need to do that.
Since fetch doesn't support beforeSend—that's specific to jQuery's $.ajax. In fetch, you need to include headers directly in the options object to globally set the Authorization header for all fetch API requests in your JavaScript file.
You can create a wrapper function around the fetch API that automatically includes the token in the headers.
So, you should have funtion like below in your js script file and whereever, you need to pass the auth header, you can link the script and call the function and pass the request URL.
async function fetchWithAuth(url, options = {}) {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    const headers = new Headers(options.headers || {});
    if (token) {
        headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
    }

    const fetchOptions = {
        ...options,
        headers: headers
    };

    try {
        const response = await fetch(url, fetchOptions);
        if (response.ok) {
            const contentType = response.headers.get('Content-Type');
            if (contentType && contentType.includes('application/json')) {
                return await response.json();
            } else if (contentType && contentType.includes('text/html')) {
                return await response.text();
            } else {
                throw new Error('Unsupported content type: ' + contentType);
            }
        } else {
            if (response.status === 403) {
                window.location.href = '/Users/AccessDenied';
            } else {
                throw new Error('Network response was not ok.');
            }
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Fetch error:', error);
        throw error;
    }
}

Considering your scenari, you could call the function as following:
 async function loadPage(url) {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
        const content = await fetchWithAuth(url, { method: 'GET' });
        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = content;
    }


UserController the user with the admin role can change the password,
create/delete users.

Well, in that scenario, before executing creation and deletion, you could check the userRole. For instance, you could write  [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")] before your controller action. Same goes for other operation.
Apart from that, based on your other question, I have already explain and given you the guideline above. If you directly want to execute read-write operation within the controller then you could use designated role in Authorize attribute.
Yeah, rest of your code seems okay.
Note: If you need additional details, please refer to this official document.

Ok, what about the fact that you said that I am using JWT Token based authorization and Identity at the same time, what do I need to redo so that only pure jwt token authentication remains, I need to stop using UserManager/SignInManager and just create a DB in which I will store the login and password, say, and independently check that the entered data in Login.cshtml matches the actual data in the database, then issue a jwt token to the user and everything will work???

It’s just not what I want. I want that after receiving the token, the user could, go to another link himself and the token would be sent with the request, but as I understand it, the implementation you propose will only work if there is a js script on the page that will execute the request and integrate the response into the current page. After a little searching, so far the most suitable option that I found is passing the token to the cookie, and then adding it to the Authorization field with help middleware or OnMessageReceived, or this is not the right thing to do when working with JWT?

First of all, you don't need to redo anything, just used token claims to allow user doing their stuff. I am not sure why you want to get rid of UserManager/SignInManager. Issuing token would ensure what you have planed. Yeah reusing token, you can also use cookie to check your token in request header as well.

Wouldn’t it be redundant to use ASP .NET Core Identity in conjunction with JWT, I just used Identity to create a database to store user data, maybe I should have written all the processing myself, without using a ready-made, more functional solution for these purposes or is it not something worth paying attention to??

Either is alright, it depends on requirement and preference. All you need to consider when the request landed, need to check if the user authorized and has the correct role to access the endpoint they requested for. That's it.

What about the token's CSRF vulnerability if I pass it via Cookie? My goal is to do everything as correctly and safely as possible. When you receive a token yourself and make requests via Postman and pass a token yourself, everything is good and simple, but when you want to make everything convenient for an ordinary person who wants to log in and get to the site, implementation problems arise. Maybe your solution more convenient for SPA. And yet, Cookies can also be blocked for receiving, in which case my token cannot be received through it by the server, because the user did not save it?

In that scenario, use Secure, HttpOnly, and SameSite attributes for cookies to enhance security and mitigate CSRF.
